# SQL Username drives me crazy

Tags: sql, psql

I am on this tutorial: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/

I'm doing everything described in psql, but I always fail when it comes to the username input. What am I doing wrong here?

Screenshot with error message is here: [image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like you shouldn't run `pg_restore -U postgres -d dvdrental C:\temp\dvdrental.tar` while within psql. Try running it in the normal Windows command line instead.

Answer (score 0):

*(Caveat: I'm unfamiliar with Windows psql, but I'm familiar with the Linux psql)*

When starting up psql in the manner that you're describing, you just have to press enter a few times. The server, database, port and username are already filled in with the values in square brackets, so pressing enter will use those values. Once you get to a prompt that looks like this:

```
postgres=#
```

...then you can run the`CREATE DATABASE dvdrental;` command.

After creating the database, type `\q` to return to your Windows command line *(may not apply, in which case, open a fresh Windows command line)"*. From here, you can follow the rest of your tutorial starting at "Load the DVD rental database"